# Connecting multiple esp8266 offline

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am planning to setup multiple esp8266 in my home to control electric appliances offline using browser.

I want to connect to single esp8266 as a controller(Master) using browser/mobile and all other esp8266 as Slave with Master so that I should communicate to Master and then it will further communicate to the interested Slave. So the communication must be Browser/Mobile -> Master -> Interested Slave.

Approaches I am aware and/or found on Google are

1. **MQTT** - https://github.com/martin-ger/uMQTTBroker
2. **Mesh** - https://github.com/Coopdis/easyMesh
3. **Client-Server** - default example provided in Arduino IDE for client and server

I already tried to all of the above methodology that I am aware of but for some reason none of these found to be useful for my application or I must have doing something wrong hence expected help from community because the scenario(one to many or vice versa) I am trying to implement is obvious and most of you must have done this.

Challenges I am facing implementing this idea with mentioned approaches are:

MQTT : (I don't want to use RaspberryPI) I am using library uMQTT broker on master and subscriber on all other slaves and obvious client app(MQTT lens) on windows desktop app so that each slave will listen to specific topic and work as expected. Challenge: uMQTT broker on esp8266 is only able to connect to one subscriber at a time, pretty strange

Mesh : I used MESH library so that I could be connect to master and then master could be connected to all other slave Challenge: In Mesh, I am not able to identify specific slave may/may not be with chip id so that to be control from master. Apart from this I am only able to connect single slave and no other slaves are even searchable

Client-Server: In this approach what I understood is, unless and until client request to server, server don't respond it means I cannot have single server and multiple client because I want to serve to clients so the instruction will be in one direction only(may be response will be in another direction i.e. request = browser->master->slave and response = browser<-master<-slave) hence this approach will not serve my purpose. There are so many examples available collecting data from sensor being slave and then sending that data to specific server esp8266 which is not applicable for my case.

So I was planning for creating multiple server(Slave) and connect then with single client(Master). Here client(Master) will act like server and client both. Now here I will instruct client and it will instruct interested server. But this approach is not yet practically tried and I don't know whether it is doable or a good approach to go for.

Apart from this one more approach is TCP IP communication but I don't know whether this will solve my purpose or not.

Please help me understanding the best case scenario to go for as per my application. I am using default examples for testing purpose with slight modifications.

Comment: Find out why 1st method failed. https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&hl=en-ca&ei=u1oqW8b3NYO0jwSh9aW4AQ&q=as+STA%2C+as+AP+mqtt&oq=as+STA%2C+as+AP+mqtt&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...6085.9247..10179...0....153.683.0j5......0....1.........0i71j33i160.gGLciVm2LPk%3D

Comment: ESPNOW is probably a lot better way to go that wifi

Comment: I am so sorry for messy question and late reply and thanks for reply. I am able to manage connection with uMQTT broker on esp8266. But it is having some limitations with limited number of connections which is 4.

Comment: @dandavis As per ESPNOW documentation '_Limited encrypted peers. 10 encrypted peers at the most are supported in Station
mode; 6 at the most in SoftAP or SoftAP + Station mode. Multiple unencrypted peers
are supported, however, their total number should be less than 20, including
encrypted peers._' so again only 6 peers can be connected at the most hence I did not gave a try to ESPNOW. For my case I wants multiple peers to be connected locally